display SVG with gaussian blur in wxPython
I want to display in a wxPython frame an SVG image that uses a feGaussianBlur. The following example shows the image but the gaussian blur is not applied. I checked the SVG code, and it seeems fine.
Please note that this is a minimal test, but I intent to use this code in a context where SVG code is not stored in a file but generated by some code. Also, the background color needs to be set outside of the SVG code.
Am I doing something wrong? Or whould I switch to another renderer than wx.svg?
import wx
import wx.svg
import numpy as np
import utils

class MyClass(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(400, 400))
        
        self.svg_filename = "uiIcons\\Smart_views\\Dance.svg"
        self.backgroundColor = "rgb(255,0,0,255)"
        self.foregroundColor = "rgb(0,0,255,255)"
        
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Show()
    
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        width, height = self.GetSize()
        
        buffer = wx.Bitmap(width*2, height*2)
        pdc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self, buffer)
        try:
            dc = wx.GCDC(pdc)
        except:
            dc = pdc
        
        dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
        
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.backgroundColor))
        dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, height, height)
        

        self.blur_bmp = self.CreateBitmapFromSvg(width, height)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.blur_bmp, 0, 0)
        
    
    def CreateBitmapFromSvg(self, width, height):
        svg = """
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs id="defs1">
            <filter
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="gaussianblur" x="0" y="0">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
            </filter>
        </defs>
         <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="200" fill="blue" filter="url(#gaussianblur)"/>
    </svg>
        """
        
        img = wx.svg.SVGimage.CreateFromBytes(str.encode(svg))
        
        dcdim = height/2
        imgdim = max(img.width, img.height)
        scale = dcdim / imgdim
        imgwidth = int(img.width * scale)
        imgheight = int(img.height * scale)
        x = int((width-imgwidth)/2)
        y = int((height-imgheight)/2)
        
        bmp = img.ConvertToBitmap(scale=scale, width=imgwidth, height=imgheight)
        
        return bmp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyClass(None, "Mon application")
    app.MainLoop()


Currently, wxPython is based on wxWidgets 3.2 which uses nanosvg to render SVG images. nanosvg does not support Gaussian blur. wxWidgets 3.3 will have a new SVG rendering library, however Gaussian blur is not currently supported in that library either.

Thanks for your answer. Are you aware of any SVG rendering library that supports gaussian blur and can interface with wxPython?
